# No properties in common with type 'Properties<string | number, string & {}

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Here is my component:

```
const linksContainerRef  = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const linksRef = useRef<HTMLUListElement>(null);

    const toggleLinks = () => {

        setShowLinks(!showLinks);
    };

  interface LinkStyles {
    heigh: string;
  }

  const linkStyles: LinkStyles = {
    heigh: showLinks? `${linksRef.current?.getBoundingClientRect().height}px` : '0px'
  };

    return (
        <nav>
            <div className='nav-center'>
                <div className='nav-header'>
                    <div className='logo'>
                        <FaMusic />
                    </div>
                    <button className='nav-toggle' onClick={toggleLinks}>
                        <FaBars />
                    </button>
                </div>
                {showLinks && (
                    <div className='links-container' ref={linksContainerRef} style={linkStyles}>
                        <ul className='links' ref={linksRef}>
                            {links.map((link) => {
                                const { id, url, text } = link;
                                return (
                                    <li key={id}>
                                        <a href={url}>{text}</a>
                                    </li>
                                );
                            })}
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                )}
            </div>
        </nav>
    );
```

};

I've got a TypeScript error saying:

```
Type 'LinkStyles' has no properties in common with type 'Properties<string | number, string & {}>'
```

I think there is a conflict between string in LinkStyles interface and  in linksRef

Any idea how to resolve this issue?
I'm new to React with TypeScript.

Answer (score 0):

OK I've figured out the solution, not sure if it's the best way but it works.

```
interface LinkStyles {
    [Key: string]: string;
  }
```